# Why is the app crashing when instantiating view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to push a new view controller but crashes on the first line with this error message

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I've double-triple checked the class name and storyboard id and they are correct. Not sure what the issue is.

```
func showUsers() {
  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "group") as! GroupViewController
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Any message in console?

Comment: @Larme no message in the console.

Comment: in your storyboard Groupviewcontroller have identify by group ?

Comment: Yes @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: Is there any IBOutlet not connected but you're trying to set a value?

Comment: let HV = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HV!, animated: true) do like this

Comment: @Matz all outlets are connects. @HimanshuMoradiya, got error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: yeah okay, I'm sure your vc is nil and the cast to GroupViewController fails

Comment: Check if you have set the view controller's Storyboard ID to "group"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check that your `vc` is not nil?

You have optional `storyboard` and force `as`, there is a couple of things that can go wrong before you push your `vc`. It can be `nil`, or it can be not a `GroupViewController` instance.

You could start by trying something like this:

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "group") as? GroupViewController {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

and see if you actually get non-nil `vc`.

EDIT: per your comment - it seems you do get `nil` at some point. Then you need to check where exactly. Is your `self.storyboard` non-nil?

Can you instantiate your view controller? [method docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller)

> If the specified identifier does not exist (or is nil) in the storyboard file, this method raises an exception.

I suggest to debug by breaking you instantiation into separate steps and check each of them like this:

```
if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "group") 
    if let groupVC = vc as? GroupViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(groupVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it was failing at `if let storyboard = self.storyboard`. Works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below given points:-

1) Please check for the GroupViewController resides in same storyboard or not

2) Debug the code and check for vc object it should not be nil.

3) Please check for **group** identifier of GroupViewController in particular storyboard.